# Python-Pyglet- Sound player stops after ~1-minute

Tags: python, macos, audio-player, pyglet

Hey so my music stops playing after ~1 minute. The sound file is ~15 minutes long, so it shouldn't be stopping. It also makes other sounds in the program not work. I am also trying to set the player to loop, so if someone knows how to do that please check my code. Any help appreciated!

```
import pyglet

music = pyglet.media.load('warmusic.wav', streaming= False)

player = pyglet.media.Player()
player.queue(music)

player.volume=.5
player.eos_action='loop'
player.play()
pyglet.app.run()
```